# Move files based on filename to different folders

Tags: batch-file, file-io

I have 1000's of files that are named like this in a directory called "Phone Recordings"

```
[Jeff Reese] 10-20-2012 at 19_39_57.amr
[Jessie Tuttle] 11-26-2012 at 17_29_15.amr
[Jody Huth] 10-19-2012 at 19_49_56.amr
```

To complicate things our recording system changed from .amr to .3gp in 2013 like this:

```
[Kim DeBouver] 10-21-2013 at 09_47_41.3gp
```

I have also noticed there are other problems as well with this such as:

```
[Jason R Tuttle] 10-26-2012 at 17_24_40.amr
```

and worse of all...

```
[9154323469] 10-24-2012 at 18_38_25.amr
```

I would like to be able to run a batch file or any other utility that may be out there to move each of these files into a separate sub directory like this:

```
\Phone Recordings\[Kim DeBouver]\2012\ (all of the 2012 recordings)
\Phone Recordings\[Kim DeBouver]\2013\ (all of the 2013 recordings)
```

For each name they will have their own folder and inside each name will have their own year for the recorded date.

I don't mind having a batch file inside the folder as long as it doesn't move that during all of the other moves.

It doesn't need to scan recursively.

I thought I had something close when I did this:

```
for %%f in (*.*) do call :handlefile %%f

:handlefile
set pad=e:\Phone Recordings
for /f  "delims= tokens=1,* " %%a in ("%1 %2 %3") do call :step %%a %%b
echo "%fn%" "%pad%"
@exit /B

:step
if !%2!==!! EXIT /B
if !%2!==!at! EXIT /B
if !%3!==!! EXIT /B
if !%3!==!at! EXIT /B
set pad=%pad%\%1 %2
for /f  "delims=_ tokens=1,* " %%a in ("%1 %2 %3") do call :step %%a %%b
@EXIT /B
```

Any help would be great, I think I am heading down the wrong track with this... Also can RegEx be used on the Windows command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the other options... I know I specified DOS Batch files and I have tested the other batch file which did work, with a little editing.

Since I am more of a PHP programmer, I ended up purchasing a program called ExeOutput for PHP, this little handy utility allowed me to create a script in PHP and run it in Windows. Pretty amazing. Anyways here is the script I created and decided to use.

NOTE: You can use this for yourself if you change the regex in both places to suite your needs.

```
<?php
# Open the directory and get files
define('PATH', 'E:/phonetemp');
foreach (find_all_files(PATH) as $file){
    processFiles($file);
}

function find_all_files($dir) {
    $value = '';
    $result = array();
    $root = scandir($dir);
    foreach($root as $value) {
        if($value === '.' || $value === '..') {continue;}
        if(is_file("$dir/$value")) {
            if (preg_match('/(\[[A-Za-z0-9]{2}.*\]\s[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}\sat\s[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2})\.[A-Za-z0-3]{3}/', "$dir/$value")) {
                $result[]="$value";
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
function processFiles($file){
    $result = '';
    preg_match('/(\[[A-Za-z0-9].*\])\s([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-)([0-9]{4}).*/', $file, $result);
    # echo '0='.$result[0].' 1='.$result[1].' 2='.$result[2].' 3='.$result[3].'<br />';
    if (is_dir(PATH.'/'.$result[1].'/'.$result[3])) {
        if(rename(PATH.'/'.$result[0], PATH.'/'.$result[1].'/'.$result[3].'/'.$result[0])) {
            echo '<span style="color: green">moved '.$result[0].' to folder '.PATH.'/'.$result[1].'/'.$result[3].' successfully<br /></span>';
        } else {
            echo '<span style="color: red">moving '.$result[0].' to folder '.PATH.'/'.$result[1].'/'.$result[3].' failed<br /></span>';
        }
        if (file_exists(PATH.'/'.$result[0])) unlink(PATH.'/'.$result[0]);
    } else {
        if (mkdir(PATH.'/'.$result[1].'/'.$result[3], 0, true)) {
            if(rename($result[0], PATH.'/'.$result[1].'/'.$result[3].'/'.$result[0])) {
                echo '<span style="color: green">moved '.$result[0].' to folder '.PATH.'/'.$result[1].'/'.$result[3].' successfully<br /></span>';
            } else {
                echo '<span style="color: red">moving '.$result[0].' to folder '.PATH.'/'.$result[1].'/'.$result[3].' failed<br /></span>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<span style="color: red">Creating Directory '.PATH.'/'.$result[1].'/'.$result[3].' failed<br /></span>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=u:\recordings"
SET "destdir=u:\destdir"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.amr" "%sourcedir%\*.3gp" '
 ) DO (
  FOR /f "tokens=3delims=- " %%i IN ("%%b") DO (
   ECHO MD "%destdir%\[%%a]\%%i"
   ECHO move "%sourcedir%\[%%a]%%b" "%destdir%\[%%a]\%%i\"
  )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

This should set you going.

You'd need to set `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your system.

It generates a `dir` list in basic (filename-only) form from the source dir for the two extensions you specify and tokenises into `%%a` and `%%b`. `%%a` gets the portion between the brackets and `%%b` the remainder of the name.

`%%b` is then analysed using `-` and <kbd>space</kbd> so the third token, the year, is assigned to `%%i`

Then create the directory and move the sourcefile to it.

The current batch would simply list the proposed commands. Remove the `ECHO`s to activate.

Note that appending `2>nul` to the `MD` line would suppres the error message generated for the second and subsequent attempts to create a directory (since it would have been created when first encountering a name+year.)

Adding `>nul` to the `move` line would suppress the `1 file moved` report.

Comment: Thank you for that, I will keep this handy for another use. I was a pretty good Batch programmer in the 80's... HAHAHA

Answer (score 1):

try it with [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
dir /b /a-d|sed -r "s/(\[.*\])\s[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]-([12][09][7-901][0-9]).*/md \"\1\\\2\"\&move \"^&\" \"\1\\\2\"/e" >nul 2>&1
```